# Using scrapy LinkExtractor with Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, scrapy

Is there a way to somehow use selenium to process javascript along with LinkExtractor? I want to crawl websites and pickup pdf files on the pages. Many of the PDFs are only available after javascript has been executed.

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver 
from scrapy.http import Request

class Fetcher(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Fetcher"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/"]

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), follow=True, callback='parse_item')]

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super(Fetcher, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS
        self.links = open("links.txt", "a")
        self.pdfs = open("pdfs.txt", "a")

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        #Do stuff

    def parse_item(self, response):
        #Do stuff

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(Fetcher)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use a [DownloaderMiddleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html) to get these requests and use selenium to download the page and return the HtmlResponse back to the spider. Something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class SeleniumMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() # Or whichever browser you want

    # Here you get the request you are making to the urls which your LinkExtractor found and use selenium to get them and return a response.
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        body = self.driver.page_source
        return HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)
```

Remember to add the middleware to your settings:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middlewares.SeleniumMiddleware': 543,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just so I understand, does this mean the links found by LinkExtractor will get processed by process_request then get passed as a response to parse_item? Would this mean LinkExtractor would also find links that are only found after javascript's executed?

Comment: It should behave exactly like that. Every Request in scrapy goes through every assigned downloadermiddleware, through every process_request until a response is returned, then it goes through the process_response methods(not used here) until eventually the response is passed to the parse methods, in this case with the full html rendered(after selenium's get)

Comment: Great. Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is great and I've got Selenium processing requests. However, I've added `"DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": {'scraper_scrapy.middlewares.SeleniumMiddleware': 1000}` to my scraper's `custom_settings` but it seems to run as the default rather than run if no `response` is returned? When I remove this setting then the standard request processor runs. I haven't made any changes other than this to `custom_settings` so not sure what's happening?