# I can't fill the items in scrapy in python

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm a beginner in Python and scrapy. I'm creating a spider in scrapy, not as a scrapy project but in anaconda. In spyder, I am considering to fill some items, but by the beginning I can't fill any variables starting by the url, followed by the price (precio in spanish), I really don't understand why scrapy can't pass any item. In my opinion, I'm adding the domain correctly, as well as the start_urls and the rules. My script is called c21.py and I run the code as follows:

```
scrapy runspider c21.py
```

Here is my complete code

```
from scrapy.item import Field, Item 
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class inmueble(Item):
    link = Field()
    precio = Field()
    
class QuotesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name='century21'
    allowed_domains=['century21mexico.com']
    start_urls=['https://century21mexico.com/busqueda/tipo_departamento-o-penthouse/operacion_venta/uso_habitacional/']
    user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36'
    
    rules={
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/pagina_'), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/propiedad/4'), follow=True, callback='parse_item'),
        }
    
    def parse_item(self, response):
        
        item = ItemLoader(item=inmueble(), response=response)
        item.add_value('link', response.request.url)
        item.add_xpath('precio', '//*[@class="col-sm-12 h5"][2]/text()')
        
        
        yield item.load_item()
```

And this is the result in the anaconda prompt

```
C:\Users\Bienvenido\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\__init__.py:131: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: ('The -t command line option is deprecated in favor of specifying the output format within the output URI. See the documentation of the -o and -O options for more information.',)
  feeds = feed_process_params_from_cli(
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.1.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 21.2.0, Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020), cryptography 3.1.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT': '3', 'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: c8f4e3cb30d55d72
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-09-13 13:38:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://century21mexico.com/busqueda/tipo_departamento-o-penthouse/operacion_venta/uso_habitacional/> (referer: None)
2021-09-13 13:38:37 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-09-13 13:38:37 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 375,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 29107,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 13.580124,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 13, 18, 38, 37, 865630),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 13, 18, 38, 24, 285506)}
2021-09-13 13:38:37 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
C:\Users\Bienvenido\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\__init__.py:131: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: ('The -t command line option is deprecated in favor of specifying the output format within the output URI. See the documentation of the -o and -O options for more information.',)
  feeds = feed_process_params_from_cli(
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.1.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 21.2.0, Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020), cryptography 3.1.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT': '3', 'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: c8f4e3cb30d55d72
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-09-13 13:38:24 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-09-13 13:38:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://century21mexico.com/busqueda/tipo_departamento-o-penthouse/operacion_venta/uso_habitacional/> (referer: None)
2021-09-13 13:38:37 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-09-13 13:38:37 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 375,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 29107,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 13.580124,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 13, 18, 38, 37, 865630),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 13, 18, 38, 24, 285506)}
2021-09-13 13:38:37 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: this page uses `JavaScript` to add elements to HTML - but `scrapy` can't run `JavaScript`. You may need to use scrapy with `Selenium` or `Splash` which can control web browser and run `JavaScript`. There should be special extensions for `scrapy`  to run it with `Selenium`

Answer (score 0):

This page uses `JavaScript` to add elements to `HTML` - but `scrapy` can't run `JavaScript`. You may need to use `scrapy` with `Selenium` or `Splash` which can control web browser and run `JavaScript`.

There is even module [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium) for this - but it didn't work for me with your code.
But maybe it will work for you.

---

I found other question [Using scrapy LinkExtractor with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45532265/using-scrapy-linkextractor-with-selenium) and using example code I created version which work with your code. It may need more changes to run without displaying browser, etc. You may try to see source code for [middlewares.py](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium/blob/develop/scrapy_selenium/middlewares.py) in `scrapy-selenium` for more ideas.

I created version which everyone can put in one file and run it `python script.py` without creating project in scrapy.

```
from scrapy.item import Field, Item 
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class Inmueble(Item):  # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames` for classes
    link = Field()
    precio = Field()
    
class QuotesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'century21'  # PEP8: spaces around `=`
    
    allowed_domains = ['century21mexico.com']
    
    start_urls = ['https://century21mexico.com/busqueda/tipo_departamento-o-penthouse/operacion_venta/uso_habitacional/']
    
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36'
    
    rules = {
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/pagina_'), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/propiedad/4'), follow=True, callback='parse_item'),
    }
        
    def parse_item(self, response):
        
        item = ItemLoader(item=Inmueble(), response=response)
        item.add_value('link', response.request.url)
        item.add_xpath('precio', '//*[@class="col-sm-12 h5"][2]/text()')
        
        data = item.load_item() 
        print(data)
        
        yield data

# --- SELENIUM ----

from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class SeleniumMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        #self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    # Here you get the request you are making to the urls
    # which your LinkExtractor found and use selenium to get them and return a response.
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        body = self.driver.page_source
        return HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)

    def spider_closed(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        
# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1

    'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
        SeleniumMiddleware: 800,   # use Selenium with all requests
    }    
})
c.crawl(QuotesSpider)
c.start()
```